# Movie in which a group of friends are driven to an abandoned warehouse full of vampires

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I remember that a group of friends went inside a container van/truck full of blood bags. Then the truck went to an abandoned warehouse full of vampires, to feed them. The last part is when a girl, one of the protagonists, saw her parents and they told her that she is a vampire too.

The vampires were similar in appearance to the ones in *30 Days of Night*, with black eyes.

I think I watched it between 2010-2013. And I bet it was made in the late 2000s, 2007-2009.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, you mentioned that a girl was one of the protagonists. Can you tell us anything about the other protagonists?

Comment: And how do you feel it was like "30 Days of Night"? Was it set in an area with prolonged night? Similar cinematics?

Comment: @LogicDictates, all I know is the girl and her friends. I think I watched it between 2010-2013. And I bet the made on late 2000s, 2007-2009

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Similar to the vampires appearance on 30 days of the night. The setting first is inside the container van/truck with a full of blood bags. Then, the truck went to an abandoned warehouse with a full of vampires to feed. I'm sorry but it was not a prolonged night. Just a normal day like afternoon on a country side.

Comment: @LogicDictates thank you that's prowl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ***[Prowl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1559033/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2010).

> Amber dreams of escaping her small town existence and persuades her friends to accompany her to find an apartment in the big city. When their transportation breaks down, she and her friends gratefully accept a ride in the back of a semi. But when the driver refuses to stop and they discover the cargo is hundreds of cartons of blood, they panic. Their panic turns to terror when the truck disgorges them into a dark, abandoned warehouse where blood-thirsty creatures learn to hunt human prey, which, the friends realize, is what they now are the human prey fighting to save their lives the realize they must work together but will they survive..

The main character, Amber, is an 18-year-old girl who -- upon learning from her alcoholic mother that she was adopted -- decides to leave the small town she grew up in to rent an apartment in Chigaco. A friend agrees to drive her there and a few more friends tag along, but their car breaks down in the middle of nowhere. They then hitch a ride in the back of a passing semi-truck, which turns out to be loaded with cardboard boxes full of blood bags, and are driven to a dark, abandoned warehouse populated by vampire-like creatures with mostly black eyes. The word 'vampire' is never actually used in the film, but they drink blood, have sharp teeth, can crawl up and down walls and leap inhuman distances. They're led by a woman named Veronica, who mostly keeps her distance as they attack and kill the main characters.

[image: Image of a vampire-like creature from "Prowl."]

In the end...

> ... when cornered by a large number of the creatures, Amber instinctively leaps high up a wall and clings to it. Veronica then comes forward and explains that Amber must be one of their kind -- a "late bloomer" who's "finally awakened" -- and that's she's been taking in and training other stray members of their kind for years. Amber asks if Veronica is her mother, but Veronica says she isn't, and that birth amongst their kind is a "violent process" which almost always kills either the mother or the child, hence the large number of orphans among their kind, Amber included.